# ¿ Cómo hacer login con mi aplicación en facebook con http y no https?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, login, url, facebook

Hola estoy creando una aplicación con Node.js y en la cual puedes registrarte mediante facebook.
Bien, he creado la API de facebook y seguido todos los pasos y documentación requerida, menos la url.
Yo tengo una url en pruebas, pero facebook no me permite el registro en mi aplicación con facebook.
He repasado documentación y buscado por google sin éxito.
Imagino que dando soporte SSL a la URL se solucionaría, pero no se que debo hacer, si debo comprar un certificado SSL solo para hacer las pruebas, teniendo en cuenta que la url es también de prueba,
Si alguien se encontró con este caso y puede asesorarme, Gracias.

> EDITO: Lo que intento decir es que el servidor utilizado esta en el hosts de mi maquina, localhost. Gracias

Comment: Dudo mucho de que ningún servicio de internet medianamente serio siga permitiendo ningún acceso por HTTP (prueba: escribe en el navegador http://www.facebook.com y mira que pasa). Pero puedes mostrar el código que has usado para intentar la conexión por HTTPS y explicar el problema que encuentras.

Comment: No estoy usando https si no http, pues como digo, mi aplicacion esta en un servidor local